# What is the best way to let Google know the difference between a Production, Development, and Staging environment?

Tags: magento, google-chrome, phishing

We have three domain names with pretty close to duplicate content (Magento sites). Let's call them `production.com`, `development.com` and `staging.com`.

I have robots no-index on `development.com` and `staging.com`. I also have htpasswds enabled. A Google search of these domains shows that they haven't been indexed. However, I'm starting to get phishing warnings from Chrome when I log in to the back end of the software.

I need to stop this as soon as possible. If the warnings spread to the front end we're looking at pretty serious ramifications.

What is the best course of action?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  What makes you think the phishing warnings are connected to your development servers? On which sites do you get those warnings? Have you excluded the possibility that it's something else (like malware serving JavaScript)? Are you subscribed to Google's Webmasters program? I think the console there gives you more info when stuff like this happens?

Comment: The warnings started appearing on the development servers and had just recently effected the live. Yes, I have webmaster tools, It isn't reporting any issues. I'm looking into other issues in tandem but the phishing warnings for the development server started shortly after deploying the development site.

Comment: Might have more luck on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You'll have to find out what causes those warnings. You won't be able to tell Google "hey, this is just my dev server so please don't show the warning" - if that were possible, everyone would do that before they send out their phishing mails

Comment: I cross posted to webmasters. Thanks Alan.

Answer (score 0):

Through robots.txt make sure google finds disallow and will not spider servers that are not production server.

Also elaborate on what warnings are being raised.